# Requesting for internet connection initiation for background service

Tags: android

What is the best way to initiate the internet connection from a background service?

My app is running periodically each 30 mins (with alarm manager triggering an alarm and that triggers a background service), from the background service, I need a working internet connection. But since the phone is in sleep mode, the wifi service is also sleeping. My question is, how to initiate / activate the internet connection (wifi/mobile) from my code? I can keep looping waiting for a valid connection but I wonder what is the bast practice for this.

I haven't been able to find any reference in the google samples regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to acquire a wake lock.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the android documentation:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                                          "MyTag");
wl.acquire();
/* screen will stay on during this section */
wl.release();
```